# how to detect WASD keypresses on PyGame

Tags: python, pygame, keypress

I am trying to detect the WASD keys being pressed on the keyboard, however, it won't detect the keypresses. Other answers on Stack Overflow didn't help so I don't think this is a duplicate.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
level = 0
abort = False
while not abort:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            abort = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if onPlatform == True:
                    onPlatform = False
                    ytarget = ylevel + 100
            if event.type == pygame.K_a:
                print("a")
                xlevel = xlevel-2
            if event.type == pygame.K_d:
                xlevel = xlevel+2
```

Here is the error I get (fixed):

```
    if event.type == pygame.K_A:
AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'K_A'
```

EDIT: comments suggested making K_a lowercase, this has fixed the error, but is now simply not responding to keypresses.

Comment: I think that's supposed to be `pygame.K_a` (lowercase a)

Comment: Thanks, this has fixed the error, it now isn't responding to keypresses. @Henry

Comment: It should be `event.key == pygame.K_a`, not `event.type`